# SendMessage causes InvalidHandle dllerror to handle that should be valid

Tags: vb.net, winapi, vb6, ipc, unmanaged

I am doing interprocess communication between a VB6 app and a VB.NET app to get control names and property values from VB6 into a .NET project. I send a request for a control in a VB6 collection using the hwnd as the key and sending the property I need as a string in a CopyDataStructure. Then I use the api function SendMessage with WM_CopyData and a CopyDataStructure to send the value back to VB.NET

From VB.NET (where PropInfo is a CopyDataStructure):

```
SendMessage(p_hwndTargetHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Me.Handle, PropInfo)
```

Which is received by VB6:

```
If KeyExists(p_colControls, CStr(lCtlhWnd)) Then
  Dim sPropVal As String
  Dim lPropValLen As Long
  Dim ctlControl As Control
  Set ctlControl = p_colControls.Item(CStr(lCtlhWnd))
  sPropVal = CallByName(ctlControl, sPropName, VbGet)
  lPropValLen = CLng(Len(sPropVal))
  sPropVal = StrConv(sPropVal, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim PropInfo As cds
  Dim j As Long
  PropInfo.dwData = lCtlhWnd
  PropInfo.cbData = lPropValLen
  PropInfo.lpData = StrPtr(sPropVal)
  Dim sError As String
  sError = Err.LastDllError
  j = SendMessage(lMsgDesthWnd, WM_COPYDATA, UserControl.Hwnd, PropInfo)
  sError = Err.LastDllError
End If
```

The SendMessage sends the message back to the Me.Handle sent to it from .NET.

In .NET I have the following:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
  If m.Msg = WM_COPYDATA Then
    GetPropValues(m.LParam)
  End If

MyBase.WndProc(m)

End Sub
```

The method GetPropValues should take the pointer to the CopyDataStructure and convert back to a string with the requested control property value. However, my .NET WndProc never receives the message. Everything is fine up until the SendMessage line in the VB6 code. Note the line `sError = Err.LastDllError` before and after SendMessage. This is 0 before SendMessage and 1400 afterwards, which is an InvalidHandle error.

What I find confusing is that I use almost this exact same method to get control names prior to getting control property values and the handle is perfectly valid and as far as I can tell the .NET handle doesn't change during the process.

Does anyone have any thoughts what the problem with the .NET handle is? Or if there is some other issue that is causing Windows to throw an InvalidHandle error?

Edit: Another piece of info that may be relevant, the .NET project is a DLL that inherits NativeWindow and obtains a handle via NativeWindow's CreateHandle method.

Comment: 1400 says that the window handle is invalid. What papens if you check the handle with IsWindow first? Does Windows accept it?

Comment: Can you post what the VB6 definition of SendMessage is?

Comment: SendMessage definition is
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As cds) As Long

Comment: IsWindow returns zero both before and after the sendmessage. How can I make sure I am getting a valid handle to send back to, if the Me.Handle sent from .NET to VB6 isn't valid by the time VB6 sends info back?

Comment: Are you sure that the "handle" you try to send to in VB6 is correct? Double check the vb6 code that read it (from wParam) when receiving the WM_COPYDATA message.

Comment: Is Me.Handle the same value as that reported by (say) Spy++?

Comment: Did you fix it or just lose interest?